# Email validation in ReactJS is not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, state

I have onSubmit function in react, added some if/else statements to validate my inputs, everything is working fine, but not for email. It keeps saying that i entered wrong email adress.

Also, can you look at my code to check if i can write it shorter?

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {

const { firstName, lastName, email, eventDate, validation, errorMessage} = this.state
if (firstName, lastName, eventDate, email) {
  this.setState({validation: true})
} else {
  this.setState({validation: false});
  this.setState({errorMessage: 'Please fill in all fields'})
  console.log(errorMessage);
}

if (/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/.test(email)) {
  this.setState({validation: true})
} else {
  this.setState({validation: false});
  this.setState({errorMessage: 'Please enter correct email adress'})
  console.log(errorMessage);
}

if (validation) {
  const newEvent = {
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    email: this.state.email,
    eventDate: this.state.eventDate
  }

  this.props.addEvent(newEvent);

  this.setState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    eventDate: ''
  });
}

e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: `new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15}/g).test(email)` please try this way.

Comment: you should have given some test strings in your question.

Comment: You did not enable case insensitive modifier, there must be `/i` at the end of the regex. `/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the sample below for email validation:

```js
console.log(new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15}/g).test('sddsfdgsg'))
console.log(new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15}/g).test('arulgetsolute@gmail.com'))
console.log(new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15}/g).test('arulgetsolute@gmail.'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `case insensitive` match (just add the letter `'i'` to your regex), like this:

```
if (/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(email)) {
```

Now you should get both uppercase and lowercase letters correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator to handle all of that for you.

```
import validator from 'validator';
validator.isEmail(value)
```